# How do I concatenate strings within an array of objects nested inside another array of objects?

Tags: javascript

Here's the JSON object I'm working with:

```
var object = {
    "units": [
        { "unitNum": "1", "fuels": [{ "fuelDesc": "Coal" }] },
        { "unitNum": "2", "fuels": [{ "fuelDesc": "Pipeline Natural Gas" }] }
    ]
}
```

What's the most performative way of concatenating all of the `fuelDesc` strings into one string, separated by `,`?

NOTE: I've simplified the object here. The actual objects is a lot larger so I'm concerned with performance. Also, the fuels array can have more than one item.

The result would be "Coal,Pipeline Natural Gas".

I did this:

```
var fuelsStr = "";
for (i = 0; i < units.length; i += 1) {
    var mergedFuels = [].concat.apply([], units[i].fuels)
    var unitFuelStr = mergedFuels.map(function (mergedFuels) {
        return mergedFuels["fuelDesc"];
    }).join(",");
    fuelsStr += unitFuelStr;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Why should performance even matter here, do you have a huge object that warrants the question of efficiency?

Comment: So your desired output is just a plain comma-separated string? Could the nested `fuels` arrays have more than one item in them, or will it only ever be one each like in your example? Use the `.map()` method with `.join(',')` on the results. By the way, [there's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), you just have an object.

Comment: Performance will matter because it's a huge object. I've just simplified it here. Also, yes, the fuels arrays could have more than one item.

Comment: If `.map()` (or a nested `.map()` for your nested array) isn't fast enough just do the `for` loop equivalent. (But I'd try `.map()` first.)

Comment: is it actual JSON string that is parsed with JSON.parse ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try a nested .map() function at this point.

Answer (score 2):

For JSON string, the [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) can be used:

```js
a = [], j = '{"units":[{"unitNum":"1","fuels":[{"fuelDesc":"Coal"}]},{"unitNum":"2","fuels":[{"fuelDesc":"Pipeline Natural Gas"}]}]}'

JSON.parse(j, (k, v) => k === "fuelDesc" ? a.push(v) : 0)

console.log(a + '')
```

For JavaScript object, the [`JSON.stringify` replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) :

```js
a = [], o = {"units":[{"unitNum":"1","fuels":[{"fuelDesc":"Coal"}]},{"unitNum":"2","fuels":[{"fuelDesc":"Pipeline Natural Gas"}]}]}

JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => k === "fuelDesc" ? a.push(v) : v)

console.log(a + '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on assumption that you always have one element inside the fuels array. you can use **`.map`** and **`.join`** together

```js
var myobject = {"units":[{"unitNum": "1","fuels":[{"fuelDesc":"Coal"}]},
{"unitNum": "2","fuels":[{"fuelDesc":"Pipeline Natural Gas"}]}]};

var result = myobject.units.map(function(elem){
    return elem.fuels[0].fuelDesc;
}).join(",");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code, you're discouraging effort. Also - `fuels` can have more than one item.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a combination of javascript's [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) functions

```js
var object = {
  "units": [{
    "unitNum": "1",
    "fuels": [{
      "fuelDesc": "Coal"
    }]
  }, {
    "unitNum": "2",
    "fuels": [{
      "fuelDesc": "Pipeline Natural Gas"
    }, {
      "fuelDesc": "some fuel"
    }]
  }]
};

var myStr = object.units.reduce(
  (first, second) =>
  first.fuels.map(item =>
    item.fuelDesc)
  .concat(second.fuels.map(item => item.fuelDesc))).join()
  
  console.log(myStr);
```

I believe this is just about as efficient as you can get, but its been a while since ive done math involving big O so if someone can prove me wrong let me know!